# How to solve a div positioning issue

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

I have a test site here:

http://www.hugoproject.com/test.html

I'm trying to put a second row of the book icons beneath the first, but whatever I try doesn't work. The following code makes a single book icon appear:

```html
<div class="project">
<a href="#" class="HS" class="project-link">Arrow<span></span></a>
</div>
```

When I have two sets of the code, two icons appear, when there are three sets of the code three icons appear. But if I have four or more sets of the code still only three icons appear. I want for the extra sets of code to make icons beneath the first three.

Also at the moment when you resize the browser window this makes the icons resize dynamically. I'd like to keep this feature and make both rows of icons fit on the one page such that there is no scroll bar.

Any ideas?

**HTML**

```html
<div id="content">
<div id="home-projects-wrapper">

<h1 class="home">Hello! My name is Brandon</h1>

<div id="home-projects">
<div id="projects" class="circle">
<div class="project-group">

<div class="project">
<a href="#" class="HS" class="project-link">Arrow<span></span></a>
</div>

<div class="project">
<a href="#" class="HS" class="project-link">Arrow<span></span></a>
</div>
                                           <div class="project">
<a href="#" class="HS" class="project-link">Arrow<span></span></a>
</div>

<div class="project">
<a href="#" class="HS" class="project-link">Arrow<span></span></a>
</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
#container {
    transition: left .3s;
    -moz-transition: left .3s;
    -webkit-transition: left .3s;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
#container.open {
    left: 270px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: left .3s;
    -moz-transition: left .3s;
    -webkit-transition: left .3s;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
#content {
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 1170px;
    margin: 7% auto;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 22px;
    color: #777777;
}
.page-template-page-templateshome-php #content {
    width: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: static;
}
.single-post #content { width: 60% }
#home-projects {
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
#projects { width: 100% }
.project-group {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
.project {
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    width: 33.3%;
    height: 100%;
}
.project-link {
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-color: #adadad;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80%;
}
.circle .project-link,
.circle .project-link .hover {
    border-radius: 100%;
    -moz-border-radius: 100%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
}
.project-link .hexagon-top {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
    border-left-color: #dfdfdf;
    border-right-color: #dfdfdf;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}
.project-link .hexagon-bottom {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-top-color: transparent;
    border-left-color: #dfdfdf;
    border-right-color: #dfdfdf;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}
.project-link .hover {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    background: #ec6136;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .3s;
    -moz-transition: all .3s;
    -webkit-transitin: all .3s;
}
.project-link .hover-text {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 45%;
}
.project-link .hover-text:after {
    content: '>';
    font-family: 'icon';
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
.project-link:hover > .hover { opacity: .9 }
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like in your css (style.css) you have this :

```css
.project-group{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Just switch absolute by relative and your second row will appear. Is it enough for you?

```css
.project-group{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Yeah it does shows the second row now but there's a scroll bar - ideally both rows should fit on one page without a scroll bar and the icons should resize with the browser window

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend removing `height: 100%` from the `.project` and `.project-group` classes in your stylesheet. My guess is that setting a 100% height on an element is interacting poorly with the `overflow: hidden` statement from `#home-projects`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to double the height of `#projects` and set the height of `.project` to 50%.

What do you mean by:

> Also at the moment when you resize the browser window this makes the icons resize dynamically. I'd like to keep this feature and make both rows of icons fit on the one page such that there is no scroll bar.

Comment: I've tried implementing your solution but no success :/

I meant if you change the size of your browser window, to say approximately half of the screen, the icons on the test page will shrink proportionately.